# SQL INNER JOIN using CASE and 3 tables

Tags: sql, join, datatables

I have the following tables and want show only the types that are available, while counting the products in that category.

Types

| Type_Id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Candy |
| 2 | Chocolate Bar |

Products

| Product_Id | Name | Type_Id | AvailabilityId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Chocolate Name 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | Chcoolate Name 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 3 | Candy Name 1 | 2 | 2 |

Availability

| Availability_Id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Available |
| 2 | Reserved |
| 3 | Sol d |

Desired Result

| Type_Id | Name | TotalAvailable |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Candy | 1 |
| 2 | Chocolate | 2 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with a basic [JOIN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/joins?view=sql-server-ver15) between all three tables, on the related columns. Note use of [table aliases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_(SQL)) `t` - Types, `p` - Products, `a` - Availability

```
SELECT * 
FROM   Types t 
         INNER JOIN Products p ON p.Type_Id = t.Type_Id
         INNER JOIN Availability a ON a.Availability_Id = p.Availability_Id
```

Next add a [WHERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/where-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) clause to filter results by the availability status:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   Types t 
        INNER JOIN Products p ON p.Type_Id = t.Type_Id
        INNER JOIN Availability a ON a.Availability_Id = p.Availability_Id
WHERE  a.Name IN ('Available', 'Reserved')
```

**Results:**

```
Type_Id | Name          | Product_Id | Name           | Type_Id | Availability_Id | Availability_Id | Name     
------: | :------------ | ---------: | :------------- | ------: | --------------: | --------------: | :--------
      1 | Candy         |          1 | Chocolate Name |       1 |               1 |               1 | Available
      2 | Chocolate Bar |          2 | Chcoolate Name |       2 |               2 |               2 | Reserved 
      2 | Chocolate Bar |          3 | Candy Name     |       2 |               2 |               2 | Reserved
```

Finally [COUNT(*)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/count-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) the total rows matched, grouping by category (i.e. `[Type].[Name]`)

```
SELECT t.Type_Id
       , t.Name AS Type_Name
       , COUNT(*) AS Total_Products
FROM   Types t 
        INNER JOIN Products p ON p.Type_Id = t.Type_Id
        INNER JOIN Availability a ON a.Availability_Id = p.Availability_Id
WHERE  a.Name IN ('Available', 'Reserved')
GROUP BY t.Type_Id
         , t.Name
```

```
Type_Id | Type_Name     | Total_Products
------: | :------------ | -------------:
      1 | Candy         |              1
      2 | Chocolate Bar |              2
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/bdd64/1)

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining it to me. I have a question though. Why you put 2 parameters on WHERE clause? (Available, Reserved). I googled it and it seems a way to specify multiple parameters, would not that be counting Available and Reserved items? Tried to modify the query but results are the same. Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, it is a way to say return records that are either "Available" *or* "Reserved". I think I only included both to match your desired results, but you can use just "Available" if it returns what you need

Answer (score 1):

You can use an inner query with inner join to achieve this. Here's a SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/42bd7f/2